# this.props.match.params is empty even when passing params

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass `params` to `this.props.match` in my React component but even after passing I still got `params` as empty object.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="boxx">
        {this.state.data.map(ele => (
          <div className="smallbox" key={ele.id}>
            <Link
              to={`${this.props.match.url}/movie1`}
              onClick={() => this.fetchOneMovieData(ele)}
            >
              <img
                src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${ele.poster_path}`}
                alt="movie pic"
              />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}

        <Route
          path={`${this.props.match.url}/:topicId`}
          render={props => (
            <OneMovie
              {...props}
              data={this.state.data}
              moviedata={this.state.moviedata}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
      {console.log(this.props.match)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a `Router` and `withRouter()`, to access `props.match`

For example you can use a `BrowserRouter` and `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` like this:

**App.js:**

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">                    
                <BrowserRouter basename='http://localhost:3000'>
                    <Route exact path='/:myparam' component={MyComponent}/>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**and MyComponent.js:**

import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        console.log('props match', this.props.match);
        return <h1>MyComponent</h1>
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Visiting `http://localhost:3000/asdf` on the app from above leads to the console output:

> props match Object { path: "/:myparam", url: "/asdf", isExact: true, params: {…} }

you can then access the value of :myparam on `this.props.match.params.myparam`, which gives you in this example:

> asdf